# what's the best practice of Flutter Navigator 2.0 for large app?

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigator

My mobile app is written in angular and ionic. It has many and many pages. Now I want to rewrite it in flutter.

I read many articles for flutter navigator 2.0. They always like below.

```
class MyAppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<MyAppConfiguration>{

  String? _selectedColorCode;
  String? _selectedShapeBorderType;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Page> stack = [
      HomePage(),
      if(_selectedColorCode != null){
        ColorPage(),
      }
      if(_selectedShapeBorderType != null){
        ShapeBorderPage(),
      }
    ];
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: stack,
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
        if (selectedShapeBorderType == null) selectedColorCode = null;
        selectedShapeBorderType = null;
        return true;
      },
    ); 
}
```

They use many properties in RouterDelegate to describe all the router state and many if-else to create current page stack.

```
class MyAppConfiguration {
  final String colorCode;
  final ShapeBorderType shapeBorderType;
  final bool unknown;

  MyAppConfiguration.shapeBorder(String colorCode, ShapeBorderType shape)
      : unknown = false,
        shapeBorderType = shape,
        loggedIn = true,
        colorCode = colorCode;

  MyAppConfiguration.color(String colorCode)
      : unknown = false,
        shapeBorderType = null,
        loggedIn = true,
        colorCode = colorCode;

  MyAppConfiguration.home()
      : unknown = false,
        shapeBorderType = null,
        loggedIn = true,
        colorCode = null;

  MyAppConfiguration.unknown()
      : unknown = true,
        shapeBorderType = null,
        loggedIn = null,
        colorCode = null;

  bool get isUnknown => unknown == true;
  bool get isHomePage => unknown == false && loggedIn == true && colorCode == null && shapeBorderType == null;
  bool get isColorPage =>  unknown == false && loggedIn == true && colorCode != null && shapeBorderType == null;
  bool get isShapePage =>  unknown == false && loggedIn == true && colorCode != null && shapeBorderType != null;
  bool get isSplashPage =>  unknown == false && loggedIn == null;
}
```

And they use a Config file which has so many properties to describe all routes for map to url.
This solution is so terrible when my app has so many pages.
Is there a graceful solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Do not confuse routes with children widgets. How many screens does the app have? You can create routes for the main pages, i.e if it's a market place, use routes to define login page, customer home page, edit profile page, display product details, checkout page, order history page.

Everything else inside those can be separate widgets without having to create routes for all of them and define them in your main.dart.

Comment: Thanks. over 50 pages and unceasing grow.  You mean one Route for  many page of a business flow? And maintain pages jump only switch widgets in the page?

Comment: Yeah, routes should control workflow or logic paths, this also helps keep your app dynamic, you can't only have the routes which you defined when you compiled the app, this would be fighting the framework, not harnessing its power. Keep it simple, but dynamic, it's more powerful. This will come with practice, and you will find plenty of help down the line.